# ffmpeg eats up / cannot read variable names from script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

The following text file ("myTextFile.txt") is used to cut a video into chunks

```
00:00:00.0 video_name_1.mp4
00:10:00.1 video_name_2.mp4
00:20:00.1 video_name_3.mp4
```

First columns are time stamps of cutting points [HH:MM:SS.millis].

I use the following command to read the txt file and cut a video called "input_video.mp4" into clips of 10 seconds each

```
while read line ; do 
  start_time=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1);
  output_name=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2);
  ffmpeg -ss $start_time -t 00:00:10.0 -i input_video.mp4 ${output_name}; 
done < myTextFile.txt
```

but it's not working. The output filenames are corrupt and I don't know why. I'm not using any special characters in the output filenames. Why is this happening?

My current work around is printing the last line ("ffmpeg ...") into the console and then paste all commands into the console command and thereby executing them...

Comment: Your input-file and script don't match each other. The script expects three fields, while the file only provides two.

Comment: This explains -nostdin option : https://superuser.com/a/1492515/1127143

Comment: @Philippe Thx for the hint. Though I don't fully understand what the problem is. How is ffmpeg aware of the fact that it is executed as part of a while loop?

Comment: Update: adding `-nostdin` does the trick!

Comment: `ffmpeg` reads standard input, which causes problem to `read line`. You can check by removing `-nostdin` option and adding `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null`, which should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the number of fields do not match.
You are specifying the duration with the `-t` option, without using
`stop_time` in your ffmpeg command. Besides you will need to put `-nostdin` option to disable the input via stdin. Then please try instead:

```
while read -r start_time output_name; do
    ffmpeg -y -nostdin -ss "$start_time" -t 10 -i input_video.mp4 "$output_name"
done < myTextFile.txt
```

Comment: sorry, that was mistake. I had an alternative version of the script with start and stop time, but it had similar issues. I fixed my question

Comment: Have you tried my script abyway?

Comment: I tried multiple versions, but only posted a minimal working example. Your answer seems to be missing the trick of adding the the `-nostdin` option as pointed out by Philippe

Comment: I just tested your solution. It still has the above mentioned bug. Please add the `-nostdin` option to your answer so I can accept it